# java.lang.nullpointerexception in ServerSocket.accept()

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to receive images over a network, I set up a server as follows

```
 public class IServerActivity extends Activity {
   ServerSocket ss = null;
   Bitmap bp ;
   Thread myCommsThread = null;
   protected static final int MSG_ID = 0x1337;
   public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);       
      this.myCommsThread = new Thread(new CommsThread());
      this.myCommsThread.start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      try {
         // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
         ss.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         switch (msg.what) {
         case MSG_ID:
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView01);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bp);;
            break;
         default:
            break;
         }
         super.handleMessage(msg);
      }
   };
   class CommsThread implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
         Socket s = null;
         try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            Message m = new Message();
            m.what = MSG_ID;
            try {
               if (s == null)
                  s = ss.accept();
               bp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(s.getInputStream());   
               myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But it shows an error at runtime

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
E/AndroidRuntime(3047):atExample.IServer.IServerActivity$CommsThread.run(IServerActivity.java:68)
```

It shows null pointer exception at **s=ss.accept();** line.
please help I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: is "ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );" throwing an exception? PLease check the console, whether "e.printStackTrace();" was executed

Comment: No, "s=ss.accept(); " throws a null pointer exception. and yes "e.printStackTrace()" was executed.

Comment: please help I am stuck at this..

Comment: Note that the "I" character in front of your class name usually refers to an interface. And your class here is not an interface. This is just an observation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a null pointer exception at that line, it can only mean that the earlier:

```
ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );
```

statement did not return normally.  That is the only *plausible* way that `ss` could be `null`.

---

(Actually, there is one other *possible* explanation.  Since the `ss` variable is package private and not `final`, some other class in the same package *could* reach in and assign `null` to it.  But I wouldn't think that was plausible.  Why would anyone write code to do that?)

Comment: and what can I do to let  "ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );" return normally.

Comment: It is impossible to say unless you tell us what exception it is throwing.  You've written a stacktrace to System.err ... tell us what it contains.